# Best way to modify content from index.php to single.php?

Tags: content, single, read-more

My blog has simple posts including a youtube videos. For example:

```
<iframe width="460" height="342" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PkxteedBq9g?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and index.php will echo content (  )

I want that the permanent link of this post ( single.php ) displays:

```
<iframe width="700" height="505" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PkxteedBq9g?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

.. it's the same video but with different width and height.

What will be the best and easy way?

( should i use  and try to work the excerpt and content someway? )

That also leaves to another question: how to show some content in the index.php and different content in the single.php page ?

Many thanks,
Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use custom fields for the YouTube video URL and then use `get_post_meta();` to pull out the URL, then in your template files (index.php, single.php) set up the embed code on each template.

Comment: Alex, great tip!
Worked as a charm using:
<?php $key="full-video"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?> 
where i could define custom field full-video

Many thanks,Pedro